# User's ID doesn't match user_id in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a table named user. The id is generated on the fly.

I have a HABTM table. I am trying to insert a record during the user registration. For some reason I can't get the user's id and the user_id to match.

This looks correct, even my array reflects the right information, but the actual data stored is not right.

code:

```
$this->request->data['User']['id'] = String::uuid();
$this->request->data['Company']['Company'][0]['user_id'] = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
```

returned array:

```
Array
(
[User] => Array
    (
        [email_address] => asdf@asdf.com
        [id] => 4fc9a939-3e24-4c79-85d1-6c28e4ca782d
    )

[Company] => Array
    (
        [Company] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4fc9a939-1840-4c1b-8bd2-6c28e4ca782d
                        [company_id] => 4fc990dd-edb0-4559-bb7b-6a00e4ca782d
                        [user_id] => 4fc9a939-3e24-4c79-85d1-6c28e4ca782d
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

So it appears that it would work based on the array I got, but it doesn't save like that. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what is saved instead? What's the type of the id field in the table? Why do you have one `Company` nested inside another?

Comment: Type is varchar(36), it is saving two separate UUID, the user's id is generated to one that I don't expect, the user_id is the one I generated for it. The nested company is how you define the HABTM relationship in an array before save().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because cake autogenerates id to UUID (when field is string and length is 36) take a look at [CakePHP API - Model->save()](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#l-1693)

Comment: Understandably. The question is, how do I get my companies_users table to reflect the same user_id as my user table's. This is the goal I'm working to accomplish.

Comment: How you saving data? What methods using? etc. please add more samples

Comment: I'm using $this->User->save($this->request->data) to save the data. What else do you need to see?

Comment: Maybe you created wrong associations, so it saves-retrieves wrong data. There is many things that can be wrong. also why you are saving   like ['company']['company'] ... ? take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: Probably multiple ways to do this, but the solution (for me) was to set my user_id after the initial save, which then allowed me to grab the correct id from my users table. Then just save my HABTM record.